# Swagger Ui not load static files on asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger

i'm using swagger ui in my asp.net mvc

Swashbuckle v 5.6
asp.net  v 4.8

on local machine everythink working successfully but unfortunately after deploy website to cloud, swagger not load static content, **but** wen i navigate to these resources using chrome it's loadded successfully

i config swagger using:

```
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
             {
                 c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });
                 c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
                 c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Console - API");
                 c.ApiKey("auth")
                     .Description("API Key Authentication")
                     .Name("auth")
                     .In("header");
                 c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
                 c.IncludeXmlComments(String.Format(@"{0}\bin\docs.xml", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                 c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
             })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                c.DocumentTitle("Console - API");
                c.EnableApiKeySupport("auth", "header");
                c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "Console.API.Assets.Swagger.SwashbuckleCustomAuth.js");
                c.InjectStylesheet(thisAssembly, "Console.API.Assets.Swagger.SwashbuckleCustomStyle.css");
            });
    }
```

[image]

Do i miss any thing? dose https effects swagger load static files?

pss: i don't think this issue related to iis because i have placed a static file in root folder of the website and i was able to load it

Comment: any suggestions guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS was block simultaneous requests, and the solution was by increment maximum concurrent connections in site advance settings in IIS

[image]